# Can't get boolean method to report correct results when comparing polygons in java

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm trying to compare the inputted polygon object to the default polygon class values. All the other math calculations are correct and properly printed. The only thing I cannot figure out is why this boolean method is reporting back incorrectly. The comparison is the default polygon's number of sides and side length to the inputted polygon's # of sides and side length. If both are even, then the polygons are equal. Here's the code I wrote to represent that:

```
public boolean equals(Polygon polygon){
    boolean areEqual = false;
    double episilon = 0.0000001d;
    double difference = Math.abs((DEFAULT_SIDE_LENGTH) - length);
    if ((difference < episilon) && (DEFAULT_SIDE_COUNT == sides))
        areEqual = true;
    return areEqual;
}
```

Here's the code to print the results:

```
public static void printIfEqual
(Polygon poly1, Polygon poly2) {
    System.out.println("Before checking equals(), print polygons");
    System.out.println("poly1: " + poly1);
    System.out.println("poly2: " + poly2);
    if (poly1.equals(poly2))
        System.out.println("Polygons are equal.");
    else
        System.out.println("Polygons are NOT equal.");        
}
```

This is the result of the code:
[image: result of code]

This is what it's supposed to be.  Notice how the fourth line from the bottom is different:

[image: What it should be]

The only difference is the boolean return. I've been playing around with the debugger but to no success

Comment: I notice that you're using `DEFAULT_SIDE_LENGTH` and `DEFAULT_SIDE_COUNT` instead of `polygon.getLength()` and `polygon.getSides()`. Is it possible you meant for the equals() method to compare to the other polygon argument, instead of to the default values?

Comment: but your equal methods says that they are NOT equal since (15.13 - 15.2 = ) 0.01 is NOT smaller than episilon 0.0000001d

Comment: What types of polygons are you dealing with for equality here?  There are three properties to check for polygon equality, but there are only checks for two of the three here.  I only see #1 and #3 here.  Or are you always comparing two polygons of the same type--decagon and same angles?  (1) number of sides (2) angles between sides (3) length of the sides.

Comment: This last comment was simply based on a link I found.  https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/polygons.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial about Java object oriented programming concepts.

https://turreta.com/2020/07/26/java-object-and-its-properties-and-behaviors/

Whenever you have a class, any object instantiated with that class which calls a method of that class is the object (`this`) in question.  And any parameter with the same type of the class itself is the object you are comparing to, whenever the equals method is overridden.  This is true for a non static method, which you have.  For a static method, you would need to pass in both Polygon objects (two parameters).

So in your example, `poly1` is the instantiated object and `poly2` (Polygon polygon as parameter) is the compared object.  I just changed the object in reference to the properties length and sides.  I'm assuming length is a property in your class and I'm assuming sides is a property of your class.  The object `this` refers to `poly1` (instantiated object), but since we are in a method owned by `poly1`, we can refer to the object as `this`.  And `polygon` is the variable for the `poly2` object that is passed into the method parameter.

My answer is purely from an object oriented perspective!  I have no idea what the epsilon value is for, but I'm assuming you know the math behind it.   I'm assuming this is for percentage error checking with the observed value and the actual value, and nothing more.  And I'm also assuming the type of polygon is the same for poly1 and poly2 when this method is called, with the exact same angles between sides.

```
public boolean equals(Polygon polygon){
    boolean areEqual = false;
    double episilon = 0.0000001d;
    // double difference = Math.abs(this.length - polygon.length);
    double difference = Math.abs(this.getLength() - polygon.getLength());
    // if ((difference < episilon) && (this.sides == polygon.sides))
    if ((difference < episilon) && (this.getSides() == polygon.getSides()))
        areEqual = true;
    return areEqual;
}
```

This assumes the Polygon class also has two properties.  Just make sure in your class constructor, you define these as parameters, and set the value of these properties in the class.  And in the comments of the question, there was mention of having a method getSides() and getLength().  I added these to the code above.  That is a cleaner way of getting the value of properties.  In fact, you may need to change the access modifier of the properties if you use the commented out lines of getting the properties directly, and it's not recommended in Java.

```
int sides = 0;
double length = 0;

public string getSides() {
    return this.sides;
}

public void getLength() {
    return this.length
}
```

So if the method were static, then the method would NOT belong to a specific object, in which case you need two Polygon objects as parameters.  And you may need a different method name, since Object always has the method equals.  You were just overriding the equals method in the above version of the method.  This just shows the logic behind the Polygon class properties (length & sides) you are checking in the logic, so it's easier to understand.  But your code is clearly for a non static method!  I believe your constants (variables in upper case) in your question was just a way to get the logic to work without understanding how objects work with object orientation.  Completely understandable.

```
public static boolean equals2(Polygon polygon1, Polygon polygon2){
    boolean areEqual = false;
    double episilon = 0.0000001d;
    double difference = Math.abs(polygon1.length - polygon2.length);
    if ((difference < episilon) && (polygon1.sides == polygon2.sides))
        areEqual = true;
    return areEqual;
}
```

In your question source code, `poly1` and `poly2` are already defined.  If you were to instantiate both objects yourself, they'd look something like this.

```
Polygon poly1 = new Polygon(10, 5.13);
Polygon poly2 = new Polygon(10, 5.12);
```

Assuming the constructor had a parameter sides and length respectively.  Inside the constructor, we are setting both properties for `this` object.

```
Polygon(int _sides, double _length){
    System.out.println("Constructor with two parameters");
    this.sides = _sides;
    this.length = _length;
}
```